# Displaying user's SQL query using PHP

Tags: php, sql, html-table

Please can anyone help me with this?

I have 2 tables, location and tickets and what I have built so far is a form in a div that users enter the name of the city or town where they would like to see a live music performance. This form is submitted and an SQL statement is passed querying the location table. In another div, the users search query appears in a box on the screen. What I would like to do next is to write an SQL statement that will lookup the user's query and dynamically display the relevant ticket information from the ticket table based on the location ID.

For example, the user types in 'Newcastle' as their search query, the location table finds the city of Newcastle and displays the user's result in a div called 'tickets'..I would like to display all the fields that correspond with 'Newcastle' from the ticket table.

The locationID is the primary key in the location table and has 3 other column, city, town and postcode.
The ticket table consists of ticketID being the primary key, the locationID being the foreign Key and the other fields i.e venue, tPrice, date and time. I think the problem im having is im not passing through the variable from the users query so that the ticket table can look it up and display the relevant information.

Here is the code for the form:

```
<div id="search">

    <form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" class="searchForm"  method="post">

   <input type="text" name="citySearch" id="citySearch" class="citySearch"   placeholder="Enter name city/town..." autofocus="autofocus" />

        <input type="submit" name="ticketSearch" id="ticketSearch" class="ticketSearch" value="Search" />


    </form>

</div>
```

Here is the code to display the user's query:

```
  <div id="locationResult">

<?php

  include( 'classes/database_connection.php' );

      $cSearch = $_POST['citySearch'];

              $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM location WHERE city = '$cSearch'";

              mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
          $queryresult = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
         $city = $row['city'];

         echo $row["city"];

        }
                                       mysql_free_result($queryresult);
        mysql_free_result($qResult);

        mysql_close($conn);
    ?>

    </div>
 </div>
```

This is where I want to display the ticket results from the ticket table:

```
    <div id="ticketsResults">

    <table class="ticketResult" border="0" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
       <td><b>Venue</b></td>
               <td><b>Price</b></td>
               <td><b>Date</b></td>
               <td><b>Time</b></td>
               <td><b>Street View</b></td>
    </tr>

        <?php
            include( 'classes/database_connection.php' );

        $locID = $_POST['locationID'];
        $citySearch = $_POST['citySearch'];

                    $sQL = "SELECT locationID FROM location";

                  //Here is where I want it to display dynamic information rather than manually type the location
        $ticketSQL = "SELECT * FROM ticket NATURAL JOIN location WHERE city = 'Newcastle' ";

        mysql_query($sQL) or die (mysql_error());
            $qResult = mysql_query($sQL) or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_query($ticketSQL) or die (mysql_error());
            $result = mysql_query($ticketSQL) or die(mysql_error());


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    //  $ticketID = $row['ticketID'];

        $venue = $row['venue'];
        $ticketPrice = $row['tPrice'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $time= $row['time'];

        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>$venue</td>\n";
        echo "<td>&pound$ticketPrice</td>\n";
        echo "<td>$date</td>\n";
        echo "<td>$time</td>\n";
            echo "<td>Click to see</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";

        }

           mysql_free_result($qResult);
           mysql_free_result($result);
           mysql_close($conn);


    ?>
       </table>
    </div>
```

So basically, I'm wanting an SQL statement that dynamically displays the tickets according to the user's query. Sorry about the copious amount of code! Any help given is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use a parameterized query. String substitution is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: does noone use mysql_real_escape_string anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you do anything else I think you should work on your coding style, specifically your indentation. A quick google search should do the trick. Next look into mysql prepared statements because currently your code is unsafe. Like jordanm said, it is subject to SQL injection.

For example, if someone entered *blah' OR 'x'='x* as a city name. Your query would become

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM location WHERE city = 'blah' OR 'x'='x';
```

Basically it allows the user to do naughty things with your query, and you don't want that.

Below is a sample of how you can avoid this using mysql prepared statements:

```
// basic quick raw example
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT city FROM location WHERE city = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s',$city_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($city);
while ($stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $city;
}
```

That's all I'm going to leave you with because I feel like to answer the actual question (?) I will need to write the code for you. Goodluck

Comment: Thank you Prowla, this is fantastic! My problem seems to be with my sql statement itself. I have a variable which holds the result of the user's city search $cSearch_POST['citySearch']; but I am struggling with trying to get this sql statement correct. Im wanting to get the locationID from the location table where the name of the city the user has inputted ($cSearch) matches the city thats in the location table and what I have doesn't seem to work:


    $citySQL = "SELECT locationID FROM location WHERE city = '$cSearch' ";

Comment: You will need to debug it. For starters print out what is in $cSearch and try hardcoding a city name (that you know is in the database) into the query (or better yet, test the query on its **own** to ensure it works; cmd, mysql workbench or webcp - whatever you use). This will tell you whether you are correctly retrieving the supplied city name and if your query is in fact correct.